# ELF binary game that uses SDL mouse only goes to the right side

Tags: sdl, mouse, elf

In a game that is the type of an elf file developed using SDL im facing an issue when i move the mouse it only moves to the right side even when i move the mouse to the left. I tried using ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04 and still face the same issue. Both clean OS installations using vmware.
I have tried installing every SDL package but with no success.

Any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, basically the problem was with an option in vmware. There is an option in edit->preferences->input->optimize mouse for games that is "Automatic" by default. Set the value to  "Always" and it solves the problem of the mouse going always to the right side.